# Unity 2d android управление

Tags: android, unity3d, input

Добрый день! Сделал простую игру с управлением двумя игроками на wasd и стрелки.
В такой реализации на ПК всё отлично работает.

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        dir = Vector2.right;
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        dir = -Vector2.up;   
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        dir = -Vector2.right; 
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        dir = Vector2.up;
```

Затем решил перенести это дело на андроид. Соответственно, создал спрайты стрелочек, прикрепил к ним GUITexture,  и написал следующий код

```
public GUITexture Up1;
public GUITexture Down1;
public GUITexture Left1;
public GUITexture Right1;
void Update()
{

    int count = Input.touchCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

        if (Up1.HitTest(touch.position))
            dir = Vector2.up;
        if (Down1.HitTest(touch.position))
            dir =  - Vector2.up;
        if (Left1.HitTest(touch.position))
            dir = Vector2.left;
        if (Right1.HitTest(touch.position))
            dir = Vector2.right;




    }
```

В такой реализации ничего не работает и вообще, если я правильно понял, подобное не обрабатывает мультитач.

Видел готовые джойстики, но они в основном на Unity3d и как их прикрутить на 2d и что при этом написать - не представляю.

Видел решения через ray, но unity я изучаю совсем недавно, поэтому как работает ray вообще не понятно пока. Насколько я понял там смотрят по координатам тапа, а мне нужно чтобы тыкнул на нарисованную стрелку вверх - и сработало тоже, что при нажатии клавиши вверх на ПК.

Comment: что значит "вообще не работает"? Ошибки какие-либо есть? или молча просто ни на что не реагирует?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Скомпилировал в APK, запустил, не работают клавиши. Можно как нибудь по джойстику прицепить к этим двум персонажам? У каждого персонажа - свой скрипт. Если через цикл делать, как сейчас, одно нажатие не перебьёт управление у другого?

Comment: Что-то у вас где-то косяк в координатах возможно... Потому что мои тесты вашего кода показали хоть какую-то, но рабочесть....http://s45.radikal.ru/i107/1605/3b/87ecae2d6f9d.gif   .... Рекомендую поставить какую-нибудь отладку, визуальную, чтоб просмотреть где какие координаты..... банально в `Text UI` выводить ... Так же хочу сказать, что у `touch` есть фазы. `Begin/Moved/Stationary/Ended` .... вам надо бы опираться на них...... также вместо `HitTest` можете попробовать `if (Right1.GetScreenRect().Contains(touch.position)) {` и т.д...... Также рекомендую перейти на `Unity3d` 5 версии.

Comment: Потому что 4 версия уже в прошлом. щас все делают на 5........также скачайте в сети эмулятор андройда для этих целей... я использую сейчас `Nox app player` - он позволяет загружать `apk`, эмулировать нажатие на экран в любом месте (я показал это на gif'ке). удобнее... ну либо подключать андройд непосредственно к unity, чтоб не извращаться..... но сейчас у вас косяк где-то либо в другом месте, либо в координатах

Comment: Это 5 версия. С чего вы решили что 4?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это 5 версия и я делаю в Unity2D а не 3D. Может в этом загвоздка? Специально сделал еще одну такую кнопку, но она тоже не работает. Может ваш код чем то отличается?

Comment: ну меня смутило `GUITexture`. Вроде это можно было раньше делать только в 4 версии. а в 5 все перешли на `UI`, элементы которого имеют совсем другие типы данных............код не менял, только добавил вывод информации. Так что в условиях `if` у меня помимо `dir = Vector2.up;` просто написано показывать значение..........не путайте -`Unity3d` - это система разработки. Она так называется... я о ней говорил...... а проекты могут быть уже 2d или 3d......можете попробовать приложить вообще исходник приложения архивом чтоб посмотреть. лично я пока ошибку воспроизвести не могу с аналогичными данными

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну вот я тоже чувствую, что с GuiTexture путь какой то неверный, они у меня получились не с первого раза и не так как в руководстве(руководство было для старой версии видимо). Подскажите, как сделать аналогично без них на 5 версии?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40421/discussion-between-dmitrii-and--).

Comment: Сделайте кнопки управления через RepatButton'ы.

Comment: Когда опрашиваете кнопки лучше их через оси опрашивать `Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")`, а не на конкретные кнопки цеплять, в таком случае можно будет на каждую ось привязать как несколько кнопок, так и джойстик, и вы двух зайцев разом убьете